# Plugin that will output submitted form data for user?

Tags: plugins, forms

I have a standard HTML form that the visitor will fill out.  It consists of mostly checkboxes.  What I would like, is after the form is submitted, a page is then presented to the user showing what they checked.  For example, if the visitor checked off Checkbox A, B, and D (but not C), then upon submission they would see the following:

```
You submitted:
Checkbox Value A
Checkbox Value B
Checkbox Value D
```

Obviously I can do this with just PHP, but my client would like to be able to modify the form options.

Is there a plugin or user friendly way that this can be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gravity Forms is by far the best form plugin available for WordPress and it will allow you to easily do what you are looking for.

http://gravityforms.com

Here is an example of how to do it:

Set the confirmation to show which checkboxes were checked using the merge tags:
[image: Set the confirmation to show which checkboxes were checked using the merge tags]
[image]

[image]

This form can be placed anywhere in a page and the confirmation function loads right after the form submittal.

Comment: Thank you for not only pointing me in the right direction, but also providing a comprehensive how to.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to tell this **options framework wordpress plugin** what to do, but it is quite simple to say the least. Give it a try. Hope it works. What you are trying to accomplish, should be able to be handled by this options framework wordpress plugin.

### Download the Options Framework WordPress Plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/options-framework/

Please visit http://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin for a full description of how to define and use the theme *options framework wordpress plugin*.